# How to remove Cronjob resource?

Tags: kubernetes

I created a CronJob resource with

```
kubectl create -f cronjob.yaml
```

Now I have too much mess on my comp,cronjob attempts to create one node every

```
15 minutes
batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528876800-h8dsj   0/1       Pending              0          39m
batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528877700-d8g9d   0/1       Pending              0          24m
batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528878600-kbdmb   0/1       Pending              0          9m
```

How to perform the opposite operation?
How to delete the resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete it with this command:

```
kubectl delete -f cronjob.yaml
```

It is also possible to delete it directly by name:

```
kubectl delete cronjob batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes
```

I am not sure whether the generated Pods and Jobs also get deleted with this command. You can delete them like this:

```
kubectl delete job batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528876800
kubectl delete job batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528877700
kubectl delete job batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528878600

kubectl delete pod batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528876800-h8dsj
kubectl delete pod batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528877700-d8g9d
kubectl delete pod batch-job-every-fifteen-minutes-1528878600-kbdmb
```

This solution assumes you are using the `default` namespace. If you do not, you have to add the `--namespace $NAMESPACE` argument to `kubectl`.